# Firebase Database - getData() returns wrong snapshot if parent value change was observed

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I integrated Firebase Realtime Database into my Xcode project, in which there are two `UIViewController`s: `TableViewController` and `DetailViewController`.

The simplified database design looks like this:

```
{
    "uid1": {
         "category1": {},
         "category2": {}
    },
}
```

In `TableViewController`, I'm observing `.value` change under the current user, like so:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // dbHandle is removed in viewWillDisappear()
    dbHandle = dbRef.child(user.uid).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        // List all categories under user.uid
    })
}
```

In `DetailViewController`, I have some logic to check if there's any existing category data under `<userID>/<categoryID>`:

```swift
let categoryRef = dbRef.child(user.uid).child(categoryID)
categoryRef.getData( { error, snapshot in
    if snapshot.hasChildren() {
        // Handle error and return, since each user can have only one item for each category
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that `getData()` returns wrong snapshot if I ever visited `TableViewController` first. The parent value was returned in the snapshot, not the child specified by `categoryID`:

```swift
// 1. Visit TableViewController and observe `dbRef.child("uid1")` once, then remove observer

// 2. Then getData() returns wrong snapshot
dbRef.child("uid1").child("category3").getData { error, snapshot in
    // snapshot.value is {"category1": {}, "category2": {}}, which is wrong
    // snapshot.hasChildren() == true, which is wrong
}
```

I didn't see this issue if I never observed `dbRef.child("uid1")`:

```swift
// 1. Do NOT visit TableViewController and NEVER observe `dbRef.child("uid1")`

// 2. Directly go to DetailViewController and getData() returns right snapshot
dbRef.child("uid1").child("category3").getData { error, snapshot in
    // snapshot.value is nil, snapshot.hasChildren() == false, both are expected
}
```

Is this a bug in Firebase or is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: I've been seeing more issues in `getData` recently. Can you try the same with the `observeSingleEventOfType` API (the type would be `.value` here) to see if that gives the result you expect? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#observesingleeventof:with:withcancel:

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I tried `observeSingleEventOfType` and it seemed working as expected. Still wondering why `getData` doesn't work though, will probably create an issue in the Firebase repo.

Comment: Ooh. if you file an issue with a minimal repro please link it here too. I'll give it a try too, as multiple people reported similar issues, but our engineers have been unable to reproduce the problem so far.

Comment: Oddly enough, I am also experiencing this exact same issue, and, oddly enough, my name is Eric too. I get think Firebase's `getData()` method is broke. It always seems to be unreliable.

Comment: But I don't see how Firebase doesn't maintain this method very well considering it has a different use case than `observeSingleEvent`. The docs state that `observeSingleEvent` gets data stored locally, **not** the latest from firebase. So `getData` is often needed..yet works only 50% of the time. (many times it throws an error for me).

Comment: I have a very similar issue with `getData()`. The workaround I am using is to create an observer and immediately delete it after I get the values from the Firebase server. Not the smartest solution, though, as the `getData()` method should be doing it.

Comment: Same here. I get the expected data when using observeSingleEvent but not with getData.